# Drop down list with posts within the "add new" page

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, dropdown

Quick explanation : 
When I add a new "Company" (custom post type), I have a drop down menu listing all the companies to choose if the one i'm creating depends from another one.
I got 3 metaboxes, the dropdown is in the first one.

```
In functions.php :
<select value="<?php echo $subsidiary; ?>" name="subsidiary">
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'company');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<option value="<?php echo the_ID(); ?>" ><?php the_title() ?></option>
<?php
endwhile;
?>
</select>
```

The dropdown is listing all the companies as i want, but when i create a new company, all fields located after my dropdown take the values from the first company in my list, and i can't change them.
Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calling $loop->the_post(), you're replacing the global $post instance.  You need to call wp_reset_postdata() after your while loop.